# Call Method to LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq, methods

Hello this is for my C# assignment

I am trying to write a program that will take user inputted data for several things IE first name, last name etc... put it into a list then print it out with the first letter of each word capitalized.

I have searched for two days trying to figure this out but have had no luck. I have the data going to the list and can display it no problem but I am having an issue figuring out how to call the method inside the LINQ statement.

i have to use UppercaseWords method in my program. What I can't get is how to call it into the LINQ

** this is in my Main method ***

`// convert first letter of each word to uppercase
            var MakeCap =
            from values in PersonInfoS
            let value = values.ToUpper()
            select value;`

** This is below Main **

```
 public static string UppercaseWords(string Value)
    {


        char[] array = Value.ToCharArray();

        if (array.Length >= 1)
        {
            if (char.IsLower(array[0]))
            {
                array[0] = char.ToUpper(array[0]);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i - 1] == ' ')
            {
                if (char.IsLower(array[i]))
                {
                    array[i] = char.ToUpper(array[i]);
                }
            }
        }


        return new string(array);
    } //   end UppercaseWords
```

I have tried a lot of different ways to get it to work. I am posting the only version that it doesn't crash on even though there is no link to UppercaseWords in there.

also i have it all in one class right now. I did try to using two classes but that didn't help me any.

if anyone can just give me a push in the right direction i'd appreciate it because I am out of ideas.

Thank you in advance for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change this:

```
let value = values.ToUpper()
```

To this:

```
let value = UppercaseWords(values)
```

As an aside, you don't need to use the `let` clause in this case even though you can. so your whole query can become:

```
var makeCap = from values in PersonInfoS       
              select UppercaseWords(values);
```

Comment: wow i could kick my self thank you.. i literally had let value = UppercaseWords(Value) and (array)... thinking i needed to pull from that method but never once did i put (values).. thank you very much i will go cry in a corner now for my stupidity. haha

Comment: You’re welcome and you should not be too hard on yourself. :-)

Comment: That aside, “values” is the iteration variable meaning it’s the variable that will represent each string in the source collection. You cannot use “array” as that doesn’t mean anything in this context and “value” is the identifier that will hold the value of the String returned from the method call.

Comment: Now that i see how they connect it makes perfect sense and I can't believe I over looked it. I am glad I posted here that was an amazingly fast response. thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

This is with method syntax which is simpler in this case.

```
var cappedWords = PersonInfoS.Select(UppercaseWords);
```

Also, you should work on that `UppercaseWords` method. My advice would be to first split the string like this: `value.Split(' ')` so you have an array of the words. Then you can iterate over those words, get the first char, `ToUpper` them, and after everything `Join(' ')` them.

Comment: Yeah I have to use UppercaseWords as part of the project otherwise i would have gone a different path. thank you for the quick response